# manifests is full of errors after using version control

Tags: android, xml, android-studio-3.0

So i was adding parse push notifications and i really didn't like the way it worked so i decided to use version control to reset the project to the last checkpoint i added i used the "Hard" option and when i did my android debug manifest was **FULL OF ERRORS** even tho the main manifest is clean.

please guys help the project is live and i don't want to loose it.

that's the code:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.inc.autorobit.roboangelv2"
    android:versionCode="7"
    android:versionName="2.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="19"
        android:targetSdkVersion="26" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <supports-screens
        android:anyDensity="true"
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:resizeable="true"
        android:smallScreens="true"
        android:xlargeScreens="true" />

    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.finsky.permission.BIND_GET_INSTALL_REFERRER_SERVICE" /> <!-- Required by older versions of Google Play services to create IID tokens -->
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />

    <permission
        android:name="com.inc.autorobit.roboangelv2.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="com.inc.autorobit.roboangelv2.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:debuggable="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/icon1"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.NoActionBar" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.inc.autorobit.roboangelv2.MainActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <receiver
            android:name="com.inc.autorobit.roboangelv2.MyAdminReceiver"
            android:permission="android.permission.BIND_DEVICE_ADMIN" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.app.device_admin"
                android:resource="@xml/admin" />

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.app.action.DEVICE_ADMIN_ENABLED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <activity android:name="com.inc.autorobit.roboangelv2.DonateActivity" />

        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.VERSION"
            android:value="26.1.0" />

        <provider
            android:name="com.google.firebase.perf.provider.FirebasePerfProvider"
            android:authorities="com.inc.autorobit.roboangelv2.firebaseperfprovider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:initOrder="101" />

        <service android:name="com.google.firebase.components.ComponentDiscoveryService" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="com.google.firebase.components:com.google.firebase.perf.component.FirebasePerfRegistrar"
                android:value="com.google.firebase.components.ComponentRegistrar" />
            <meta-data
                android:name="com.google.firebase.components:com.google.firebase.iid.Registrar"
                android:value="com.google.firebase.components.ComponentRegistrar" />
        </service>

        <receiver
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurementReceiver"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="false" >
        </receiver>
        <receiver
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurementInstallReferrerReceiver"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true"
            android:permission="android.permission.INSTALL_PACKAGES" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <service
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurementService"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="false" />
        <service
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurementJobService"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="false"
            android:permission="android.permission.BIND_JOB_SERVICE" />

        <receiver
            android:name="com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdReceiver"
            android:exported="true"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />

                <category android:name="com.inc.autorobit.roboangelv2" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <!--
             FirebaseInstanceIdService performs security checks at runtime,
             no need for explicit permissions despite exported="true"
        -->
        <service
            android:name="com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdService"
            android:exported="true" >
            <intent-filter android:priority="-500" >
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>

        <activity
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiActivity"
            android:exported="false"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" />

        <provider
            android:name="com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider"
            android:authorities="com.inc.autorobit.roboangelv2.firebaseinitprovider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:initOrder="100" />

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

        <provider
            android:name="com.crashlytics.android.CrashlyticsInitProvider"
            android:authorities="com.inc.autorobit.roboangelv2.crashlyticsinitprovider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:initOrder="100" />

        <meta-data
            android:name="android.arch.lifecycle.VERSION"
            android:value="27.0.0-SNAPSHOT" />
    </application>
```

Comment: Put errors here or the print of errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have solved the problem....after checking my resources multiple times i noticed that the string.xml file was missing it looks like it has been lost during the revert operation so i re-added it and added all the strings and POOF problem gone!

Answer (score 0):

Close tag for Manifest `</manifest>` is missing at the end, if I am not mistaken this is the only missing tag.